# Python не понимает кириллицу в пути к файлу

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть две строки. Первая запрашивает папку, а вторая выбирает из этой папки все файлы. Всё хорошо работает, пока не появляется кириллица в пути. Версия Python 3.7.0.

```
folder_name = input("Folder: ")

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(folder_name) if isfile(join(folder_name, f))]
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\PP\Files.py", line 14, in create_file_list
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(folder_name) if isfile(join(folder_name, f))]
OSError: [WinError 123] Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома: '"e:\\Папа\\Новая папка\\№17 от 25.02.19\\DFT17"'
```

Как это исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы вводите путь в кавычках.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Даже стыдно за настолько тупую ошибку